# I dont understand how to feed pygeocoder a variable instead of straight up number

Tags: python, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have a database of coordinates which i set to a list like so

```
point = []
#sqlcode to append the database to point[0] point [1] point [2] et cetera.
```

So in for example point[0] i have the output:

```
(45.424571, -75.695661)
```

Then i want to do some reverse geocoding with the pygeocoder module. It works when i add the number manually like so:

```
results = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(45.424571, -75.695661)
print(results[0])
```

This gives me a print out of a correct address.

However if i do this instead:

```
results = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(point[0])
print(results[0])
```

It does not work.

Im not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. essentially i want to make this work:

```
point = []
point.append("45.424571, -75.695661") 
results = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(point[0])
print(results[0])
```

But i only get this error message in that case:

```
results = revgeo.reverse_geocode(point[0])
TypeError: reverse_geocode() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Comment: Can you explicit how the data comes out of the database? I'm not sure if you're getting a string: `"45.424571, -75.695661"` or a tuple: `(45.424571, -75.695661)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
point = []
point.append([45.424571, -75.695661]) 
results = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(*point[0])
```

The point should be a list, not string.

Comment: It's one star only, this is for a dict.